# Filter FullCalendar JSON events

Tags: javascript, json, fullcalendar

I am trying to filter the events shown on my FullCalendar, based on the value of a specific key in my JSON source. This is what the JSON looks like:

**events.json**

```
[
  {
    "start": "2020-05-22",
    "end": "2020-05-26",
    "rendering": "background",
    "cottage": "cottage-one"
  },
  {
    "start": "2020-06-22",
    "end": "2020-06-26",
    "rendering": "background",
    "cottage": "cottage-one"
  },
  {
    "start": "2020-05-01",
    "end": "2020-05-06",
    "rendering": "background",
    "cottage": "cottage-two"
  }
]
```

And this is what I have in my javascript to generate the calendar:

**script.js**

```
  var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
    plugins: [ dayGridPlugin ],
    firstDay: 1,
    events: 'events.json',
    height: 'auto',
    header: {
      left:   'prev',
      center: 'title',
      right:  'next'
    }

  });

  calendar.render();
```

This is all working great, but I only want to show the events for `cottage-one` in this particular instance. What do I need to change in **script.js** to achieve this? I have tried a couple of approaches I found on here but they were more concerned with dynamically updating a filter, and I was unsuccessful altering the syntax to suit my use case.

Any help very welcome

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [eventSourceSuccess](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventSourceSuccess) parameter to do this. From the docs:

> A function that gets called when fetching succeeds. It can transform
>   the response.

The full code would be.

```
var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
  plugins: [ dayGridPlugin ],
  firstDay: 1,
  events: 'events.json',
  eventSourceSuccess: (events, xhr) => events.filter(event => event.cottage === 'cottage-one'),
  height: 'auto',
  header: {
    left: 'prev',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'next'
  }
});

calendar.render();
```

Answer (score 0):

And how to filter with multiple parameters with "and" or "or" conditions with that syntax ?

```
eventSourceSuccess: (events, xhr) => events.filter(event => event.cottage === 'cottage-one'),
```